# Android: How do I draw a box in google maps in the right direction (please read details below)?

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, geometry, google-maps-android-api-2

My android app is to use GPS to help layout a sports field, like a football field. You enter the dimensions of the rectangle, tell the app which corner you want to start with and which corner you want to go to next. The app will tell you when you have walked far enough. Once you have laid down the first two corners, the app will then direct you to the next corner (logic in the app make sure you only select corners that make sense). This is where the trouble comes in. You may be going clockwise or counter-clockwise. I need to know which way to turn for the third point. I know how far I need to go, and I know how to figure out a right angle, but I don't know how to figure out if I went the right way.

[image: Football field]

I was thinking about forcing the user to go one way or the other, but the problem is that often times a field is laid out with an obstacle on one side (a street, cornfield, fence, whatever). In that case, you will usually want to start at the obstacle and work your way out.

So, to put the question one other way, given two points, A & B (lat & long), how can I calculate the third point that is at right angle to the segment AB and in the right direction? For example, if the user says they want to start with corner 2 and then corner 8, how do I calculate the gps coordinates for corner 7?

I realize that this is possibly/probably more of a geometry question than an android question, but it may be that there is a specific android solution.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you that this is not an Android question, but a geometry question. Nothing by default in Android to program this I'm afraid.

Great link that I use to remember how I have to calculate distances on the survace of the earth is http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html.

1. Calculate bearing between given corners (for your example, between 2 and 8)
2. Calculate bearing for next corner you want to know (bearing between 2 and 8 + 90 degrees)
3. Find destination point given distance and bearing from start point (start point is 8, use bearing calculated at step 2 and I assume you know the dimensions of the field)

Comment: https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/SphericalUtil.java contains all the functions you need for that. Especially computeOffset allows you to move a given point by a given distance into a given direction. (Point 3 of Aster's algorithm)